# Not working conditional if translating PHP to twig

Tags: php, drupal-7, twig, drupal-8

I'm translating templates of Drupal 7 to Drupal 8, I have a variable which contains the type of page displayed in the node, in PHP that comparation was using == as operator and a literal of type int as second argument, the variable  content['field_tipo'][0] outputs 5, but I think that is a entity field, so the type of data is wrong to compare with an int or string. Is there any function able to parse an entity.field to a string or int?

```
{%if ...%}
{%elseif ...%}
{%elseif content['field_tipo'][0] == 5 %}
            {%if video%}
                <div class="tipo1">
            {%else%}
                    <div class="tipo2">
            {%endif%}
                        <div class="">
                            <div class="">
                                <h3>{{content['field_'][0]}}</h3>   
                                <h1>{{title}}</h1>
                            </div>
                            <div class="">
                                <h4>{{content['field_'][0]}}</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="">
                                <h4>{{content['body']}}</h4>
                            </div>
                            </div>                  
                    </div>--><!-- fin #box_tipo -->
    {%else%}
        <h1>{{content['field_tipo'][0]}}</h1><!--entro aqui y displayeo 5-->
    {%endif%}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can compare it with just putting the 5 in quotation mark, So

```
{%elseif content['field_tipo'][0] == "5" %}
```

**but I think** you should use value property of it , something like

```
{%elseif content.field_tipo[0].value == "5" %}
```

OR

```
{%elseif node.field_tipo[0].value == "5" %}
```

Comment: I solved it, wasn't a compare problem, the problem was a value that is array type and when you output an array using tiwg the value shows rendered and {{variable}} shows 5 but contains array([0]=>5), i implemented a twig filter to know the type of the variable, and that was all. 
Thank you sir